# Generate multidimensional array from array of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with keys that describe location in a multidimensional array like:

```
array(
        '3728:baskets:4839:1' => 'apple',
        '3728:baskets:4839:2' => 'orange',
        '3728:baskets:4920:1' => 'cherry',
        '3728:baskets:4920:2' => 'apple',
        '9583:baskets:4729:1' => 'pear',
        '9583:baskets:4729:2' => 'orange',
        '9583:baskets:6827:1' => 'banana',
        '9583:baskets:6827:2' => 'pineapple',
);
```

I would like to pass this array to a function that generates a multidimensional array based on the the pieces in the keys delimited by the ":". The resulting array should look like:

```
array(
    3728 => array(
        'baskets' => array(
            4839 => array(
                1 => 'apple',
                2 => 'orange',
            ),
            4920 => array(
                1 => 'cherry',
                2 => 'apple',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    9583 => array(
        'baskets' => array(
            4729 => array(
                1 => 'pear',
                2 => 'orange',
            ),
            6827 => array(
                1 => 'banana',
                2 => 'pineapple',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Loop over the array, `explode()` the key on `':'`, put the value in the right spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function array_createmulti($arr) {
    // The new multidimensional array we will return
    $result = array();
    // Process each item of the input array
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        // Store a reference to the root of the array
        $current = &$result;
        // Split up the current item's key into its pieces
        $pieces = explode(':', $key);
        // For all but the last piece of the key, create a new sub-array (if
        // necessary), and update the $current variable to a reference of that
        // sub-array
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($pieces) - 1; $i++) {
            $step = $pieces[$i];
            if (!isset($current[$step])) {
                $current[$step] = array();
            }
            $current = &$current[$step];
        }
        // Add the current value into the final nested sub-array
        $current[$pieces[$i]] = $value;
    }
    // Return the result array
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The use of references might be non-obvious to a beginner. I'd suggest adding a small explanation to go with this otherwise nice answer :)

Comment: Awesome! This worked beautifully! I thought passing arrays by reference was going to be part of the solution, but it was not working for me. I'm glad there are smarter people in the world that can help figure this out for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster then previous answer:

```
function formatMyData($data)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode(':', $key);
        if (!isset($res[$a])) {
            $res[$a] = array(
                $b => array(
                    $c => array(
                        $d => $value
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        else if (!isset($res[$a][$b])) {
            $res[$a][$b] = array(
                $с => array(
                    $d => $value
                )
            );
        }
        else if (!isset($res[$a][$b][$c])) {
            $res[$a][$b][$c] = array(
                $d => $value
            );
        } else {
            $res[$a][$b][$c][$d] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```

[See in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8rJUuF)